# CSS Border Image: rendering a frame by rotating an image

Tags: css, border-image

I need to render a frame (ie, a picture frame around a picture) by rotating an image:

- 0 degrees for the left
- 90 for the top
- ... and so on.

As far as I can tell there isn't a `border-image-left|right|top|bottom` property, although this would work too - please correct me if I'm wrong.

It seems I'll need to use the `border-image` property. Does anyone know if possible to rotate the image depending on the side?

I guess the other messy options would include

- Creating four div's around the image
- Manually generating a frame border image (this won't really work as 1. we've got over 300 images, and 2. the frames need to be used on images with different aspect ratios... )

Edit: 'depending on the side' = 0 degrees for left, 90 degrees for top, 180 degrees for right, 240 for bottom... See image below for an example.

[Left hand border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UI1w.png)

Comment: Can you post your code in snippet what have you done so far ?

Comment: If you use `figure` and `figcaption` you might be able to use the pseudo elements to fake a border using `background-image` then just rotate the element.

Comment: Have you looked at using something like a [border-image generator](http://border-image.com/) to generate the css you need?

Comment: *" Does anyone know if possible to rotate the image depending on the side?"* Huh? Depending on the side...being shorter than the other sides?..Depending on what color the side is?...Depending if that side had good night's rest?

Comment: 'depending on the side' = 0 degrees for left, 90 degrees for top, 180 degrees for right, 240 for bottom... See https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UI1w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially forced, but wrapping it in a div and span and playing with pseudo elements and transforms seemed to work.
The image is wrapped in an `.img-container` div and a span, and the `::before` and `::after` elements are absolute positioned around the image.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="img-container">
  <span>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300?image=200">
  </span>
</div>
```

And the styling:

```
.img-container, span, img{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

/* Image border general */
.img-container::before,
.img-container::after,
span::before, span::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UI1w.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Specific to the right border */
.img-container::after{
  left: auto;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

/* Top and bottom border general */
span::before,
span::after{
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

/* Just the bottom */
span::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
}
```

May be a little much

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b94x4bfu/2/)

Comment: Thanks a million! It's a messy problem to start with... Have managed to get it working using javascript so the frame will change dependant on selection....